# NSIS FontReg, FontRegAdv and ReadRegStr + CurrentVersion

Tags: fonts, registry, nsis

We're using NSIS to install fonts along with the rest of our stuff.  The font installation isn't successful, and I've tracked it down (I think) to an issue with how the registry entries are generated.

Both FontReg and FontRegAdv have the following lines:

```
${Index}:
  ClearErrors
  ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" "CurrentVersion"
  IfErrors "${Index}-9x" "${Index}-NT"

"${Index}-NT:"
  StrCpy $R1 "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts"
  goto "${Index}-GO"

"${Index}-9x:"
  StrCpy $R1 "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Fonts"
  goto "${Index}-GO"
```

We see the registry keys being created in

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Fonts
```

which tells me that ReadRegStr is throwing an error (and so thinks this is a pre-NT-era registry).  Interestingly, the correct value is returned by ReadRegStr (6.1 -- determined by adding a MessageBox).

This is on Windows 7 64-bit.  We do see the correct parallel registry keys appearing in the Wow6432Node area.  This is running with admin privileges.  "SetRegView 64" doesn't change anything.

The documentation for ReadRegStr says that it only fails if the key isn't present; I have verified that the key is present.  Why is ReadRegStr claiming to have failed, even when it returns a (correct) value?

Comment: where would i find the NSIS version?  i see a copyright date of 2009, which suggests 2.43-2.46

Comment: makensis.exe /version and it is also listed at the bottom of the MakeNSISW window if you are using that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where you got the idea that it only fails if the key is not present. The current docs say this:

> The error flag will be set and $x will be set to an empty string ("")
>   if the string is not present. If the value is present, but is of type
>   REG_DWORD, it will be read and converted to a string and the error
>   flag will be set.

This is almost 100% correct but if the value is of some other type it will also fail.

NSIS v3.0 beta behaves like this:

```
Return     | Error | Reason
-----------+-------+-------
"" (empty) | Yes   | Cannot open key for KEY_READ access
"" (empty) | Yes   | RegQueryValueEx failed
number     | Yes   | Type is REG_DWORD
"" (empty) | Yes   | Type is not REG_SZ and not REG_EXPAND_SZ
string     | No    | Value existed and is of type REG_SZ or REG_EXPAND_SZ
```

You could try replacing the `IfErrors` check with `StrCmp "" $R0 "${Index}-9x" "${Index}-NT"` or just remove the 9x parts if you don't support Windows 95/98/ME.

I cannot explain why it fails but still reads the correct string. Have you tried taking a look with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)?

Comment: sorry, i was mis-paraprasing http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/ReadRegStr .  in this case, the key is indeed REG_SZ, which suggests that it's not failing on type.  what, specifically, would i look at with Process Monitor in this case, please?

Comment: I'd say you should set a filter: "Path" contains "CurrentVersion" and then look at the results column and see if it is success or some error code for the queryvalue operation...

Comment: I ended up removing the pre-NT parts of our local copies of FontReg and FontRegAdv and just writing to the NT+ part of the registry always; we aren't even supporting installs for things before XP.  thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you manage to catch the registry operation in Process Monitor? I have never seen this problem before and I would like to get to the bottom of it...

Comment: ProcessMonitor shows queries for the path HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\CurrentVersion, result of SUCCESS, and Detail of "Type: REG_SZ, Length: 8, Data: 6.1".  the only thing that might be odd is a length of 8, but i guess these are unicode characters and that's bytes?  however, i don't see why that would result in ReadRegStr thinking there had been an error.